# Find all items with the top 5 unique values based upon 2nd element in tuple list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I want to find the all tuple items with the top 5 max values in a tuple list based upon the 2nd element of the tuple. 
For example, I have a tuple list

```
x1 = [(a, 5), (b, 5), (c, 4), (d, 3), (e, 8), (f, 9), (g, 2), (h, 1)]
```

I want to get the following list:

```
x2 = [(a, 5), (b, 5), (c, 4), (d, 3), (e, 8), (f, 9)]
```

As the top 5 unique values for 2nd elements are 9, 8, 5, 4, 3 and a, b both have value 5, they both should be included in the list.

Any idea on how to realize this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the top 5 second elements:

```
i = set(list({x[1] for x in x1})[-5:])
```

Filter the list:

```
x2 = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] in i, x1))
```

Or even better:

```
ss = {x[1] for x in x1}
if len(ss) > 5:
    i = list(ss)[-5]
    x2 = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] >= i, x1))
else:
    x2 = x1
```

Output:

```
[('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 4), ('d', 3), ('e', 8), ('f', 9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
x1 = [('f', 9), ('e', 8), ('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 4), ('d', 3), ('g', 2), ('h', 1)]
x1.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
max5set = set()
i = 0
for _, num in x1:
    max5set.add(num)
    i += 1
    if (len(max5set) == 6):
        break
print(x1[:i-1])
```

output:

```
[('f', 9), ('e', 8), ('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 4), ('d', 3)]
```

if you want to get this tuple list alphabetically, do

```py
print(sorted(x1[:i-1], key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

output will be

```
[('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 4), ('d', 3), ('e', 8), ('f', 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sorted` and `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

func = lambda x:x[1]
res = []
n_max = 5
group_by = itertools.groupby(sorted(x1, key=func, reverse=True), key=func)
for _ in range(n_max):
    res.extend(list(next(group_by)[1]))
```

Output:

```
[('f', 9), ('e', 8), ('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 4), ('d', 3)]
```

If you want the final output to be sorted, use `sorted` once again:

```
sorted(res, key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Output:

```
[('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 4), ('d', 3), ('e', 8), ('f', 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy:

```py
def my_fun(x1, k):
    import numpy as np

    x2 = np.asarray(x1)                         # Convert to numpy array
    val = np.unique(np.sort(x2[:,1]))[-k:]      # Sort index 1 & find top 'k' unique values
    idx = np.isin(x2[:,1], val)                 # Indices of rows to retain

    x2 = x2[idx].tolist()
    x2 = list(map(tuple, x2))                   # Convert back to list of tuples
    return x2
```

```
>>> x1 = [('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 4), ('d', 3), ('e', 8), ('f', 9), ('g', 2), ('h', 1)]

>>> my_fun(x1, 5)
[('a', '5'), ('b', '5'), ('c', '4'), ('d', '3'), ('e', '8'), ('f', '9')]

>>> my_fun(x1, 3)
[('a', '5'), ('b', '5'), ('e', '8'), ('f', '9')]
```